# is that possible to send FormData along with Image file to web API from Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular4-forms

Is it possible to pass the form data along with image file to web api from angular 6 application.

app.component.ts

```
onSelectFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => this.selectedImage = reader.result.toString();
    this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToUpload);
  }
}

createNewComitteeMember() {
  var mServiceObject = {
    ComitteeMemberName: this.comittee_Member_Name.value,
    ComitteeMemberNumber: this.comittee_Member_Number.value,
    ComitteeMemberType: this.comittee_Type.value,
    ComitteeMemberTypeOthers: this.comittee_Type_Others.value,

    ComitteeMemberPosition: this.comittee_Member_Position.value,
    ComitteeMemberPositionOthers: this.comittee_Member_Position_Others.value,
    ComitteeMemberStatus: this.comittee_Member_Status.value
  }

  this.dmlService.CreateNewComitteeMember(mServiceObject, this.imageToUpload ).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);

  });
}
```

service.ts

```
CreateNewComitteeMember(mFormData,mImage){
// here how can I merge the mFormData and mImage and pass it to the web API
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: I think you should be able to pass it along with form data. What error you get? Is request being send?

Comment: I am new to this ,I don't know how to marge and pass it to API method .@Buczkowski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of FormData over here

```
CreateNewComitteeMember(mFormData,mImage){
  const HttpUploadOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"})
  }
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', mFormData);
  formData.append('image', mImage);
  return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, HttpUploadOptions)
}
```

For more info about [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 0):

To merge two objects into one you can simply do something like:

```
createNewComitteeMember(mFormData, mImage) {
   mFormData['image'] = mImage;
}
```

The main issue with what you are presenting is that HTTP has a limit to the amount of data you can POST. To get around this you need to set the Content-Type Header to 'multipart/form-data'. This means it will take HTTP multiple trips to the server to get all the data across, so combining the data together seems to be not necessary, but if you must

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData

service:

```
checkdata(selectedFile:File){
        let httpheader = new HttpHeaders();
        let options={
            headers: httpheader
        };
        const uploadData = new FormData();
        uploadData.append('File', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
        return  this.http.post('uri',uploadData,options)
    }
```

component:

```
 onSelectFile(event) {
       if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
           this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
           this.Yourservice.checkdata(this.imageToUpload)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this method it worked for me

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("userData", this.userData.value);
formdata.append("image", this.uploadedFile.value);
```