# Image upload and show then calling api to store it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am using Angular ver.8.0. 
I want to store the image in api by using this code below:

home.component.ts for uploading and showing image

```
  preview2(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.imgURL2 = reader.result;
      console.log(this.imgURL2);
      console.log(reader);
      this.med_limit2 = true;
    }
  }
```

home.component.html for upload Image

```
<input #file2 type="file" class="file_upload" accept='image/*' (change)="preview2(file2.files)" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 50%;background: #0b474a;
                border: none;">Browse</button>
``
home.component.html for showing Image
```

```
        <img [src]="imgURL2" *ngIf="imgURL2" class="presc_img" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2"
          style="max-width: 123px; min-width: 99px; margin: 0 14px;box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px grey;
          border-radius: 2px;">
```

```
 upload_image() {

    this.presc_service.uploadPrescriptionImage(this.imgURL2).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);

      this.image_upload2 = '/' + res['cart_data'][0]
      this.uploadStatus = res['status']

    });
  }
```

home.component.ts

```
onSelectFile(event) {
console.log(event);
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
console.log(this.imageToUpload);
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e => this.selectedImage = reader.result.toString();
this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToUpload);
}
}
```

I got code for storing image using api but its not previewing image

Comment: what is the error ? can you specify it in the question

Comment: *I want to store the image in api by using this code below* unable to understand! can you please explain?

Comment: the error is showing- 'undefined' @JoelJoseph

Comment: actually i want to store image using api @PrashantPimpale

Comment: You want to send images using API?

Comment: yes @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Then use formData - [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953317/is-that-possible-to-send-formdata-along-with-image-file-to-web-api-from-angular) how the API is accepting the attachment data? Can you show us?

Comment: I have used this code but it is unable to preview the image in front-end .@PrashantPimpale

Comment: @Anikesh will help if you provide stackblitz demo

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue solved.
Thanks for helping me.

home.component.ts

```
  onSelectFile(event, files) {

    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }
    console.log(event);

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {

      this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(this.imageToUpload);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.selectedImage = reader.result.toString();
      this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToUpload);


      var reader1 = new FileReader();
      this.imagePath = files;
      reader1.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader1.onload = (_event) => {
        this.imgURL = reader1.result.toString();
        console.log(this.imgURL);
        console.log(reader1);
        this.med_limit1 = true;
      }

    }
  }
```